# Can we run sqoop import statement using spark-sql or apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sqoop

Is there any way to run sqoop as spark job. Through which we can replace MapReduce execution to the Spark execution engine

Comment: The question why do you want to run it as spark?  
Sqoop executes a sql statement or copying the whole table to HDFS location, sqoop doesn’t do any transformation as such. Only it does in the MAP stage create parallel connection to your DB and copies data, there is no REDUCE stage for sqoop.  
Maybe Im wrong but in this case Spark and MR will perform same.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop doesn't have an execution engine like Pig or Hive, both of which can also connect to JDBC sources and dump into HDFS as well